# How to set a message in jquery frame dialog?

Tags: jquery, c#-4.0, dialog, message

I am creating a div and then I write a message within the same to be disaplayed, but this time  my div must also contain ID, which is dynamic, so I want to write message dynamically.
But I am not able to get how to write message within my jquery function. Below is my code:

```
 $(function confirm () {
                         $('#update-dialog').dialog({
                         modal: true,
                         buttons: {
                          Ok: function () {
                          $(this).dialog('close');
                            }
                          }
                          });
                        });
```

And my Div is :

```
 <div id="update-dialog" title="Mortgage Application Lock" style="display: none">
   <%-- <span class="textfont">This Mortgage Application is currently in use.</span>--%>
</div>
```

It must have message from function not the hard written.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$( "#update-dialog" ).dialog({open: function( event, ui ) { $(this).html("my recurring message other than hard written with html"); } });
```

Comment: have you included the jquery ui file with the page

Comment: well the simplest was to add .html(content)